# What is the best numerical algorithm for integrating the 1D Schrödinger equation?

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I'm interested in numerical algorithms for 1-dimensional Hamiltonians of the form

$$
H = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x) \quad \quad (1)
$$

defined on the line ($x\in\mathbb{R}$) or on the circle. The potential $V$ is such that the lowest part of the spectrum is made of eigenvalues.

My definition of *best* (and of 'integrating') is that the algorithm should return more accurately the lowest eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions (say the lowest $N$ with $N$ of order 10-20).

I'm aware of *Numerov's method* but I think there should be better algorithms given my desiderata.

In particular I wonder wether Krylov methods exist for my problem. The potential $V$ is given explicitly so computing $H \psi$ for a nice smooth $\psi$ is easy and in general obtaining $\langle \phi, H^n \psi \rangle$ seems possible to a certain degree of accuracy.

Bonus points if the algorithm is implemented in some (available) software package.

Comment: See this [physics.stackexchange.com question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170546/numerical-solution-to-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-eigenvalues) The answer contain cut-and-pasteable code.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you but that post seems to deal with Numerov's method. I was hoping for something a bit more advanced (without reinventing the wheel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the lowest eigenvalues by means of a [Krylov subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace) method you could use the [Lanczos algorithm,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) as explained for example in:

[Solving the discretized time‐independent Schrödinger equation with the Lanczos procedure](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.458575)

> A new method is presented to find bound state solutions of the one‐,
>   two‐, or three‐dimensional Schrödinger equation. The equation is
>   turned into a sparse matrix eigenvalue problem by representing the
>   potential energy surface and the wave function on a grid. The
>   Laplacian is represented by a high (10th) order finite difference
>   formula. Eigenvalues are found by the Lanczos procedure. Examples are
>   given for the 1D Morse oscillator and the 2D Hénon‐Heiles potential.
>   Numerical convergence can be checked easily and highly accurate
>   results can be obtained. The algorithm is fast, easy to implement, and
>   vectorizable.

Comment: Thank you this may work. Let me see if something else comes up. If not I will accept this. I was hoping to avoid to discretize space.